# Use same ViewModel property multiple time in controller to upload different item?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a property `ContractExtention`  in a view model which is datatype `HttpPostedFileBase`. The idea behind this property is to allow users to upload the contract extension, once they upload the contract extension I should be able to access the file info using the property `ContractExtention`. The problem is, it is possible for a user to need to upload more than one contract extension at once. The number of contract extension can vary.

```
[FileTypes("doc,DOC,docx,DOCX,pdf,PDF,jpg,jpeg,png")]
public HttpPostedFileBase ContractExtention { get; set; }
public List<amendcontract> amendcontract { get; set; }
```

The property `amendcontract`, will tell me how many contracts the user needs to upload. This is the code for my view:

```
foreach (var contract in Model.amendcontract)
    {
        if (contract.DocumentReceived)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Contract Extention", new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-8">

                    <div class="col-sm-4 align-items-center doc" style="width:100%">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <a href='@Url.Action("viewDocument", "Intern", new { docType = "ExtendedContract",docId=contract.ContractDocumentID })'><i class="far fa-check-circle" title="View Document" style="font-size: 37.5px; color: green; "> </i></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1" style="width: fit-content; top: 50%; transform: translateY(50%);">
                            <strong class="align-middle">Contract Extention for @contract.effectiveDate</strong>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
        }
        else if (contract.ContractDocumentID == null)
        {

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Contract Extention", new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-8">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContractExtention, new { type = "file", @class = "extendContract", @id = "uploader" })

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContractExtention)
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Contract Extention", new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-8">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContractExtention, new { type = "file", @class = "extendContract", @id = "uploader" })

                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContractExtention)
                        </div>
                        <!--
                        -->
                        <div class="col-sm-7 align-items-center doc">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <a href='@Url.Action("viewDocument", "Intern", new { docType = "ExtendedContract", docId = contract.ContractDocumentID })'><i class="far fa-file-pdf" style="font-size:50px; color:black"></i></a>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <strong class="align-middle">Contract Extention for @contract.effectiveDate</strong>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
        }
    }
```

If the `contract.ContractDocumentID` is null it means the user hasn't uploaded any file, else the user has uploaded a file but is waiting for approval. When the user gets a contract extension it is added to the amend contract table. My code will go through each item in the `amendcontract` and if the user needs to upload a file, it will use `ContractExtention` property to allow users to upload a file.  How do I allow users to upload more than one file at once, using the property `ContractExtention`?

Comment: Look into adding a property like List<HttpPostedFileBase> Files on your view model and then make your UI (using something like jquery) to add multiple file inputs

Comment: Add the `multiple` attribute to the input, and make the property `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to upload multiple files at once, is to use JQuery to collate all the files into a FormData object, post them asynchronously and then use Request.Files to receive them in your controller action instead of trying to use HttpPostedFileBase in your view model.

Since you have multiple file inputs, you'd have to iterate over all of them and add each file.

```
var data = new FormData();
$("input[type=file]").each(function(i, obj) {
                    var files = $(obj).get(0).files;
                    if (files) {
                        for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
                            data.append("file" + x, files[x]);
                        }
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(response) {

                    }
                });
```

In your controller:

```
for (int i = 0; i< Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
}
```

You should be able to adapt this to your needs.

**EDIT:**

It's also worth nothing you can add additional information into the FormData object if you need to send other parameters to your action:

```
data.append("key", "test");
data.append("value", "test");


public ActionResult Upload(string key, string value)
{
    //key = test, value = test
    var files = Request.Files; //HttpFileCollectionBase
}
```

Comment: No where has OP indicated they want to use ajax. And suggesting OP use `Request` rather than strongly binding to a model is terrible advice (and means their validation attributes will not work)

Comment: I actually didn't notice the attribute, that's poor behaviour on my part. I take your point about offering advice that OP didn't ask for though. Noted for the future.